# Amount of Classifying Time

Tags: python, memory-management, classification, nltk

I am trying to run a classifier, naive bayes, over 1.6 million tweets using nltk and python.

Please can someone tell me if this is a stupid thing to do as the process has taken about 12 hours so far and is currently using 3.2 gb of memory.

Is this just a waiting game that's affected by how good your processing power is or are there more efficient ways of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data set is very large, so you should expect a long running time and memory consumption. Its hard to tell if that is reasonable without more info.

You could however trying to use some classifiers from scikit-learn instead of the nltk basic classifiers, there are many efficient options there - K-nearest neighbors, linear regression to name a few, and also alternative implementations of naive Bayes classifiers. I have had better success classifying text with those.

[here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html) is a link to a wrapper for using them with nltk based datasets. Hope this helps..

Comment: brilliant thanks, yeah I expected it to take quite awhile but I guess not this long. I'll try to complete this classification and see how accurate it is, but definitely looking into other classifiers.